# Compute the following integrals of $z^i$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, logarithms, contour-integration

Compute the following integrals:

1. $\int_{\gamma_1}z^idz$, where $\gamma_1(t)=e^{it}, \frac{-\pi}{2}\leq t \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$.
2. $\int_{\gamma_2}z^idz$, where $\gamma_2(t)=e^{it}, \frac{\pi}{2}\leq t \leq \frac{3\pi}{2}$.

I think 1. is much easier than 2. since it does not cross the $Re(z)<0$. So for 1.
$$\int_{\gamma_1}z^idz=\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{\frac{-\pi}{2}}(e^{it})^i ie^{it}dt=i\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{\frac{-\pi}{2}}e^{it-t}dt=i\frac{1}{i-1}e^{it-t}|^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{\frac{-\pi}{2}}=\frac{1-i}{2}\left(e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}+i\frac{\pi}{2}}-e^{\frac{\pi}{2}-i\frac{\pi}{2}}\right)$$
However, for 2. we cannot apply the same method directly... Any help? Thanks!

Comment: What about splitting $\gamma_2$ in two parts one for $t\in [\pi/2, \pi-\epsilon]$ and another for $[-\pi+\epsilon,-\pi/2]$ where $\epsilon>0$? And then take $\epsilon\to 0$?

Comment: What about first providing a definition of $$z^i$$ and of the reasons why you think that $$(e^{it})^i=e^{-t}\ ?$$

Comment: @Did I am sorry if I made a stupid mistake. I just simply think that is $i^2=-1$.

Comment: Of course, $i^2=-1$. This says nothing about the meaning of $z^i$ and why $(z^v)^w$ should equal $z^{vw}$ when $(z,v,w)$ are complex numbers. Would you be taking these identities for granted?

Comment: What @Did means is the following. Define $$z^i:=\exp(i\operatorname{Log(z)})$$ where $\operatorname{Log}(\cdot)$ is the Principal Logarithm. One has $((-1)^2)^i=1$ but $(-1)^{i2}=e^{-2\pi}$ so $(z^i)^w\neq z^{iw}$ in general...

Comment: @Shashi How's my answer please?

Answer (score 2):

This is a summary of the comments to the other answer. It seems that you are using [this text book](http://math.sfsu.edu/beck/complex.html), and that this is exercise 4.19. In this chapter(Chapter 4) the integral $\int_\gamma f$ is defined only for functions $f$ that are continuous on $\gamma$, so it would seem that you should pick a branch cut of $\log(z)$ so that $z^i$ is continuous on $\gamma_2$.

Without further instruction, we don't have a unique branch cut to use, so one could get different answers. But I suspect that it wants you to use a branch cut that coincides with the principal branch on $\{z\in \mathbb C:\Im z > 0\}$. This is the choice

$$\log z = \log |z| + i\arg(z), \quad \arg(z) \in [0,2\pi)$$

In fact, with this choice, $z^i := e^{i \log z}$ is an analytic function on an open neighbourhood of $\gamma_2$, so that with $\frac{d}{dz} \frac{z^{i+1}}{i+1} = z^i$,

\begin{align} \int_{\gamma_2} z^i dz  
&= \left. \frac1{i+1} e^{(i+1)\log z} \right|_{\exp(i\pi/2)}^{\exp(3i\pi/2)} \\
&= \left. \frac1{i+1} e^{(i+1)\log z} \right|_{i}^{-i} \\
&= \frac{e^{i(i+1)3\pi/2} - e^{i(i+1)\pi/2}}{i+1} \\
&= (1/2 - i/2) (-i e^{-3 π/2} - i e^{-π/2}) \\
&\approx -0.108 - 0.108i\end{align}
since $\log i = \operatorname{Log}i = i\pi/2, \log(-i) = i\operatorname{arg}(-i) = i3\pi/2. $ This answer is distinct from the answer obtained by splitting the region into two parts $\gamma_2 \cap \{\Im z<0\}, \gamma_2 \cap \{\Im z>0\}$ and then integrating the function given by the principal log on each curve, as in the other answer; the resulting answer there is [approximately $9.03956 - 14.0579 i$.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%3D%20i%20%5Cint_%7B%5Cpi%2F2%7D%5E%7B%5Cpi%7D%20e%5E%7B(i-1)t%7D%20dt%20%2B%20ie%5E%7B2%5Cpi%7D%5Cint_%7B%5Cpi%7D%5E%7B3%5Cpi%2F2%7D%20e%5E%7B(i-1)t%7D%20dt)

Answer (score 0):

Observe $$z^i = e^{iLn(z)} = e^{iln|z|-Arg(z)} = |z|^ie^{-Arg(z)}$$

$$\therefore, \int_{\gamma_2}z^idz = \int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{3\pi}{2}} |z|^ie^{-Arg(z)} ie^{it}dt = \int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{3\pi}{2}} |e^{it}|^ie^{-Arg(e^{it})} ie^{it}dt$$

$$ = \int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{3\pi}{2}} 1^ie^{-Arg(e^{it})} ie^{it}dt = \int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{3\pi}{2}} e^{-Arg(e^{it})} ie^{it}dt$$

$$ = \int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi} e^{-Arg(e^{it})} ie^{it}dt + \int_{\pi}^{\frac{3\pi}{2}} e^{-Arg(e^{it})} ie^{it}dt$$

$$ = \int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi} e^{-t} ie^{it}dt + \int_{\pi}^{\frac{3\pi}{2}} e^{-(t-2\pi)} ie^{it}dt$$

$$ = i\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi} e^{-t} e^{it}dt + i\int_{\pi}^{\frac{3\pi}{2}} e^{-(t-2\pi)} e^{it}dt$$

$$ = i\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi} e^{(i-1)t} + ie^{2\pi}\int_{\pi}^{\frac{3\pi}{2}} e^{(i-1)t} dt$$

$$ = i \frac{e^{(i-1)t}}{i-1}|_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi}  + ie^{2\pi} 
\frac{e^{(i-1)t}}{i-1}|_{\pi}^{\frac{3\pi}{2}}$$

---

Calvin Khor edit:

By considering a different branch of the logarithm where $Arg(z) \in [0,2\pi)$ instead of $Arg(z) \in (-\pi,\pi]$ s.t. $Ln$ will be differentiable for $Re(z)<0$,

[stuff to say]

Comment: You've chosen a definition of $z^i$ that is not continuous on the path $\gamma_2$?

Comment: @CalvinKhor But I split up $\int$ anyhoo soooo what's the issue? I think it's like $\int_{[-1,1]} sgn(x) dx$

Comment: Strikes me as odd. The OP did /not/ state which branch to use, but there is a version of $z^i$ that is analytic on the left half plane that agrees with the one defined via the principal logarithm at $\gamma_2(\pi/2)$. This is what I would have decided to use, and the answer you get will of course be different.

Comment: @CalvinKhor I believe OP got from A First Course in Complex Analysis by Matthias Beck, Gerald Marchesi, Dennis Pixton, and Lucas Sabalka Exer 4.19. Does this change anything?

Comment: And can you remark on what the correct definition of $z^i$ should be based on the book which I do not have?

Comment: @CalvinKhor $a^b = e^{bLn(a)}$, and sorry the [book is actually free](http://math.sfsu.edu/beck/complex.html)

Comment: You're not understanding me, but thank for you for informing me about the book

Comment: @CalvinKhor Oh you mean choosing a different branch to make it continuous on the left half plane? I guess we can choose $Arg(z) \in [0,2\pi]$. Oh then that would make computations much simpler?

Comment: It would make it more than continuous, it would be analytic. And it would make the answer different (I believe)

Comment: @CalvinKhor Hmmmmmm.... but all branches have the same derivative $\frac1z$ right?

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow how $1/z$ relates to $z^i?$

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, in the 4th chapter of this book, the author only defines $\int_\gamma f$ for functions that are continuous on $\gamma$.

Comment: @CalvinKhor [No need to be sorry.](http://www.boredpanda.com/stop-saying-sorry-say-thank-you-comic-yao-xiao/) I'm the one who actually doesn't get something. Lol. You said $z_i$ would be analytic but then the answer would be different. Ultimately, $z^i$ is related to a log branch, but all log branches have the same derivative. I'm not sure of the exact relation, but given this, you still think the answer would be different?

Comment: @CalvinKhor continuous on $\gamma$ sooo I split up the $\gamma$'s like in Prop 4.6c?

Comment: Sorry, I'm aware its just a speech habit :) its got to be different since you're multiplying the second integral by $e^{2\pi}$, but I didn't simplify your answer to verify. With the branch above  its analytic so the answer is just $z^{i+1}/(i+1)$ at the endpoints,
$$ \left. \frac1{i+1} e^{(i+1)\log z} \right|_{\exp(i\pi/2)}^{\exp(3i\pi/2)} = \left. \frac1{i+1} e^{(i+1)\log z} \right|_{i}^{-i}$$
and $\log i = \operatorname{Log}i = i\pi/2, \log(-i) = i\operatorname{arg}(-i) = i3\pi/2$ so its
$$\frac{e^{i(i+1)3\pi/2} - e^{i(i+1)\pi/2}}{i+1} = (1/2 - i/2) (-i e^{-3 π/2} - i e^{-π/2})
$$

Comment: @CalvinKhor Post as answer?

Comment: I'm happy for you to edit your answer to include this if you think it is correct.

Comment: @CalvinKhor go ahead

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean for me to edit your answer. I think it may be better for me to post a summary as a separate answer

Comment: @CalvinKhor That's what I said initially...right...?

Comment: Yes, but I was away from my computer at the time, my apologies

Comment: @CalvinKhor Oh by 'happy for you' you mean 'allowing you' ?

Comment: @BLCC Yes, thats what I meant. Sorry :(